# How to compress a part of graph into a single node and be able to find shortest path from one node to all?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graph

I have a **graph** with the following features -

1. Has total **N** nodes (1,2...N).
2. All edges are **bidirectional**.
3. Nodes from **1 to K** (K <=N ) are connected to each other with **same weight W**.
4. And there are **M edges**. These M edges may have **different** weights. Also these M edges can be between any node to any other node ( can be between the N-K nodes or from nodes from first K ones to other N-K nodes.
5. There exists a path to reach from one node to another **for sure**.

[An example graph having these features.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWKNl.png)

I need to find the **shortest path distances** from a **given node to all other nodes**.

Now I was thinking instead of directly using Dijkstra's Algorithm to find the shortest path from a given node to all other nodes, it would be **more optimal** to **compress the subgraph of nodes 1 to K** into a single node since it would take just O(1) time to find distances from any of the K nodes to any other K node because it is **fixed with a value W** and each of the K nodes is **connected to each other**.

But I am not able to think of how to code it or modify my Dijkstra's algorithm. I want to know how to go about solving this problem and also if possible is there any better solution available?

Comment: do you know W is always smaller than the weights between N-K? Otherwise your idea of collapsing 1-K does not work, right?

Comment: actually, in your description there are not edges between "1 to K" and "K+1 to N", how can 5 be true?

Comment: While running Dijkstra's algorithm you find the shortest path to each node in order. So when you reach any of the nodes in 1-K you can add all of the nodes in 1-K to the found path with the value of P for the node you reached and P+W for all of the nodes in 1-K (The first time nothing else will have a value). One thing is you have to continue considering all of the nodes in 1-K until you're path is worse the P+W as it's possible that a later path will get you directly to the node and still be better than P+K. This should have the same big O() as Dijkstra's but in practice can be better.

Comment: @Beginner sorry, I had made a mistake in writing the 4th point of the graph features. i have changed it now.

Comment: @twain249 What do you mean by value 'P'. There isn't any value given to the nodes.

Comment: @iammangod96 I was just using P to denote the cost of a path returned by Dijkstra's. Effectively my comment is the same  kraskevich's answer just not as well describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a standard Dijkstra's algorithm with one twist: we'll keep a segment tree that supports three operations:

1. Get minimum in a range
2. Set a value in the given position to +INF
3. Make a range update (setting `a[i] = min(a[i], new_val)` for all `l <= i <= r`)

A standard segment tree can handle all these operations in `O(log N)` time.

We can take care of all "other" `M` edges in a standard fashion (we get the value for the child node, update it and put it back to the tree if necessary).

The edges between the first `K` nodes can be handled like this: if the current node `v` is among the first `K`, we make a range update to the `[1, K]` segment with a value `dist[v] + W`.

That's it. There're at most `K <= N` updates of the second type and `M` updates of the first time (like in a standard Dijkstra's algorithm). So the total time complexity is `O((M + N) log N)`, no matter how large `K` is.

Comment: Instead of segment tree, can't we use priority queue?

Comment: @iammangod96 We need range updates. A priority queue can't do it efficiently.

Comment: Your method works correctly. Thank you for your time and efforts. However I was able to solve the problem exactly the same way I was thinking of. And so I will write that solution here for future reference.And I will upvote your answer surely.